# Comunicação PWA vs App Nativo Android

Tags: android, pwa

Amigos, tenho uma aplicação para uso interno na empresa em PWA. E para uma nova demanda iremos precisar da geo localização em tempo real. Recursos que não temos ainda no service worker e sem previsão de ser liberado... E estamos partindo para a ideia de criar um App auxiliar nativo apenas para essa função.

Como só precisamos da localização em tempo real somente durante determinada tarefa, queremos ter o poder de ativa-lo e desativar o recurso conforme necessidade.

Sabendo que PWA não tem capacidade de falar diretamente com outros app, Quais as formas de comunicação vocês sugerem entre o app PWA com o app Nativo?

- Via push notification consigo ativar funções no app nativo?
- É possivel ter um serviço interno http no Android gerenciado pelo app e o PWA fazer comunicação com ele via http rest no localhost?

Comment: Eu passaria essa responsabilidade para o backend, o PWA ou o aplicativo enviaria a informação para ele e caso fosse necessário compartilha-la o backend a enviaria.

Comment: obrigado eduardo, mas o backend conseguiria disparar um comando para o app, mesmo ele estando fechado?

Comment: Acredito que sim, quando o Whatsapp está fechado continuamos recebendo mensagens, só não sei os detalhes de como é feito kk, mas acredito ser possível.